# How to embede Apache Superset chart into React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, apache-superset

I want to embed my chart from Apache Superset into my React.js App.
So far I know there is possibility to use  like this:

```
<iframe
        id="myIFRAME"
        width="1600"
        height="1200"
        seamless
        frameBorder="10"
        scrolling="no"
        src="http://localhost:8080/r/3"
      >
</iframe>
```

It works fine but I want to use only a chart with filter options without all the superset dashbord pane:
[image]

I was trying to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superset-ui/core but there is no good documentation how to use it and it require to downgrade react version to 16, while I think in my project will be better newer version.

Currently I am trying to manipulate things inside iframe by catching things by

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("myIFRAME");
  var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName(
    "dashboard-content css-185d7vi"
  );
   elmnt.style.display = "none";
```

But i think it's not a good way to do this and Im getting errors with `CORS` and `Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.`

Comment: You can find a detailed guide to embedding superset into your react app here:
https://www.tetranyde.com/blog/embedding-superset

Comment: Did you find a way? Im in the same need

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to add to iframe query attribute standalone=true..

```
<iframe
        id="myIFRAME"
        width="1600"
        height="1200"
        seamless
        frameBorder="10"
        scrolling="no"
        src="http://localhost:8080/superset/dashboard/world_health/?standalone=true"
      ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is helpful for your question.

https://superset.apache.org/docs/creating-charts-dashboards/creating-your-first-dashboard/#customizing-dashboard

```
<iframe
    width="1600"
    height="1600"
    seamless
    frameBorder="0"
    scrolling="yes"
    src="http://127.0.0.1:8088/superset/dashboard/16?standalone=2"
    >
</iframe>
```

Don't get the URL from '**Copy dashboard URL**' in superset.
Instead of that you can get the dashboard URL from the browser link address.
At the end of the URL simply add '**?standalone=2**'